# Webpack still showing old code afer changes. How do I reload webpack?

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Currently have a django/react app that I am creating.  Had some errors on my webpack that I had to change.  After doing this I tried loading the site again and for some reason the old code is still showing.  Anything I can do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called cache.

Add `[hash]` to your `output.filename` name.